# WP : Custom Post Type pagination by cats Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I'm going crazy I'm working on a wordpress mobile theme and i have an issue with the pagination of my custom post type. Explanations :

This is a winery website. On this website there is 3 cats of wine. on single-wine.php I want to be able to navigate between all wine wich are on the same cat. It doesn't work like i want and i don"t know why cause each use the same code :

Cat 1 : Dry wines - Pagination looks good

Cat 2 : Vintage wines - I can navigate only between 3 wines ( >< why ..?)

Cat 2 : oxy wines - I can navigate only between 1 wines ( >< why ..?) Next_post and previous_post function have the same link all the time.

Can you help me ? Actually i really don't understand where is the issue, i'm on it since 2 days. the single-wine query ? The pagination ?

Try it on mobile to understand : mas.triangle-fr.com

Single-wine.php

> ```
> <?php include('winecats-2.php');?>
> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
> <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>  
> <section id="wine-head">
> <div class="containerWine">
> <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<i class="left"></i>', TRUE); ?>
> <?php next_post_link( '%link','<i class="right"></i>', TRUE); ?>
> ```

Wine-cats-2.php

> ```
> <?php $args = array(
> 'post_type' => 'vins',
> 'cat' => the_category_ID($echo=false),
> );
> $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
> <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
> <header class="cat-header">
> <h3 class="wine_nav"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> <?= the_category($post->ID); ?> </h3>
> <ul id="wine-dropdown">      
>     <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
>     <li class="wine-item"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  class="" data-id="" id="<?= $post->post_name?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li> 
>     <?php endwhile; ?>
> </ul>
> ```

Comment: wine-cats.php [code<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'vins',
    'cat' => the_category_ID($echo=false),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>

<header class="cat-header">
    <h3 class="wine_nav"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> <?= the_category($post->ID); ?> </h3>

    <ul id="wine-dropdown">      
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
][/code]

Comment: is this a comment or an answer? Also please try to explain it and format your code

Comment: Hello Loic46. Please edit your post and put your comment into your post. As you it is hard to read. Also you should correct the code snippets: just use 4 blank characters at the beginning on each line and it is marked as code.

Comment: Thanx robsh i'll do it